# Difference between drawing in playground and Project for Swift

Tags: swift, drawing, core-graphics, swift-playground

I am very new in terms of drawing stuff with swift and recently I was given a code that should do what I need (Have a rectangle floor with 10 tables on it). This code seems to work perfectly in the playground (the preview "eye" on the right side shows the code invoked the image i want) but when I placed it in the ViewController under ViewDidLoad() and run the application, nothing appears. I am not really sure what I am missing as I copy and pasted the exact code into my project and it seems to not be working. I changed nothing in the storyboard and I left it as a blank view controller. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's the code.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

struct Table {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}

var tables = [
    Table(x: 2, y: 3), Table(x: 4, y: 3), Table(x: 6, y: 3),
    Table(x: 1, y: 5), Table(x: 3, y: 5), Table(x: 5, y: 5), Table(x: 7, y: 5),
    Table(x: 2, y: 7), Table(x: 4, y: 7), Table(x: 6, y: 7)]

let cafeWidth = 8
let cafeHeight = 10

let cafeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
cafeView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)

func viewForCoordinate(#x: Int, #y: Int, #size: CGSize) -> UIView {
    let centerX = Int(cafeView.frame.size.width / CGFloat(cafeWidth)) * x
    let centerY = Int(cafeView.frame.size.height / CGFloat(cafeHeight)) * y
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    view.center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    return view
}

// draw the grid
for row in 1..<cafeHeight {
    for column in 1..<cafeWidth {
        let gridDot = viewForCoordinate(x: row, y: column, size:    CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        gridDot.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cafeView.addSubview(gridDot)
    }
}

// draw the seats
for table in tables {
    let tableView = viewForCoordinate(x: table.x, y: table.y, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 100/360.0, saturation: 0.44, brightness: 0.33, alpha: 1)
    cafeView.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "cafeView" is never added to the ViewController.
Add this to the bottom of the viewDidLoad function: `self.view.addSubview(cafeView)`